# Why doesn't my map render in a jQuery tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

If I render a map in a tab which is hidden by default, then navigate to that tab (make it visible), the map does not render properly. But when I refresh the page, the map renders properly.

**Issue**
[image: Image of map not rendering properly.]

**Javascript of Google Maps**

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(serLat, serLang); // - 34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,

        width: 1270,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    (
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(serLat, serLang),
            map: map,
            width: 1270,
            title: 'Click'
        }
    );
    //        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    //            content: cntnt
    //        });
    //        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    //            // Calling the open method of the infoWindow 
    //            infowindow.open(map, marker);
    //        });
}
window.onload = initialize;
```

**URL of Jquery Tabs**
    http://quickerbook.imobisoft.eu/App_Themes/js/jquery.tabify.js

**HTML of Tabs**

```
<ul id="tabs-hd">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab for Google Map</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1">Content for tab one...</div>
<div id="tab2">Content for tab two...</div>
<div id="tab3"><div id="map"></div></div>
```

Comment: I see the code now
     // Function added to help reset map and container boundaries
        $("#showMap").click(function() {
        $("#tab2").css({'display':'block'});
        $("#map_canvas").css({'width':'630px', 'height':'400px'});
        initialize();
        //alert('showMap Clicked!');
        });
        
     initialize();

Comment: Having the same issue. One detail to note is that if you load the page and navigate to the tab before it finishes loading, the map may render properly. If you wait for the page to fully loads and then navigate to the tab, it never renders properly. (should be evidence that the code isn't broken, but rather that it is purely an issue with having it render at the appropriate time)

Answer (score 9):

There are two things you need to do:

1. When you reveal the hidden tab, make sure you properly size the container DIV the map is in.
2. Either wait until that DIV is visible and sized before creating the map in it, or else after the DIV is visible and sized, send a resize message to the map:

`google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' );`

Answer (score 1):

All I did is added a height in the style of the div element and map started appearing.

> ```
> <div class="event-details" style="height:500px;" id="map_canvas">
>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

hi i have the same problem u mast to have click on your Tab button and then you must call `initialize()`; see what i'm doing i set this function on every tabs click attribute

```
function ChangeTabs(e){
   $('#tabs-1').hide();
   $('#tabs-2').hide();
   $('#tabs-3').hide();
   $('#tabs-4').hide();

   var a = $.browser;
    if (a.msie)
    {
        $(e.srcElement.hash).show();
        if(e.srcElement.hash=='#tabs-3')
            initialize();
    }
    else
    {
       $(e.currentTarget.hash).show();
       if(e.currentTarget.hash=="#tabs-3")
            initialize();
    }
```